# Getting Constructor from Java Class that would be called for argument types, not requiring exact argument & parameter type match

Tags: java, reflection, constructor

Is there any way in Java (or in a Java library) to get the `Constructor` from a `Class` that would be called for the given arguments / argument types (not requiring exact argument & parameter type matches, instead including supertypes)?

i.e. I know about `Class#getConstructor(Class<?>)`, but that only returns exact matches.

e.g., the following code throws a `NoSuchMethodException`, whereas I want to get the `Constructor` for `A(CharSequence)`, as that's what would be called if I ran, e.g., `A("")`:

```java
public class A {

    public A(Object o) {}
    public A(CharSequence cs) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Constructor c = A.class.getConstructor(String.class);
        c.newInstance("");
    }
}
```

I imagine that such a method would also potentially throw an exception indicating that multiple constructors match, so it can't choose without the argument types being made more specific (like through explicit casts).

I'd also want to find this functionality for `Method`s.

Thanks.

Comment: You can cast ```""``` to the object you want to use. Beyond that I don't think there is a good-practice way to do it.

Comment: You can call `getConstructors()` and then apply whatever logic you want to choose one of them.

Comment: @DavidConrad Agreed. I, too, thought of using `getConstructors()` to do that, but then I'd have to learn & replicate the exact Java argument-to-parameter matching rules, which I'd rather not do, if someone else has already done it, preferably in the JRE or a much-used library.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi My problem is that I have a method that takes the `Class` to instantiate & the constructor arguments as its parameters.  I don't know beforehand what constructors the `Class` has, and which ones are supertypes of the arguments.  I need some code to inspect the `Class` & arguments to figure that out.

Comment: The easy way to do the entire task of creating the object, not just getting the constructor, is to use a `java.beans.Expression`. It follows the same type inference rules as the compiler.

Comment: @user207421 That worked.  If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it…

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085048/finding-most-specific-overloaded-method-using-methodhandle). I _really_ thought there would be such support in `MethodHandles` API...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `java.beans.Expression`.

To demonstrate the behavior:

```
public class A {
    public A(Appendable o) { System.out.println("A(Appendable)");}
    public A(CharSequence cs) { System.out.println("A(CharSequence)");}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // calls A(CharSequence)
        A a1 = (A)new Expression(A.class, "new", new Object[]{ "string" }).getValue();
        // calls A(Appendable)
        A a2 = (A)new Expression(A.class, "new", new Object[]{ System.out }).getValue();
        // ambiguous, throws exception
        A a3 = (A)new Expression(
            A.class, "new", new Object[]{ new StringBuilder() }).getValue();
    }
}
```

Note that the current version doesn’t indicate that the problem is ambiguity in the exceptional case; it’s not distinguishable from the situation when no match has been found.

A fundamental limitation is that there is no way to solve the ambiguity, as you can’t preselect a method or constructor. You would have to resort to low level Reflection with its requirement for exact matches for that.